# Is it possible to add collision to an object linked with an armature?

Tags: collision, rigidbody

I am trying to add collision to my object which is attached to a rig, as when I animate it I want it to interact with objects with rigid body or collision. But I am having hard time figuring this out as I am new to blender. Is there any way I could achieve this?

[image]

[image]

In the picture above, I want the pink Rectangle to interact with the green one so when it moves it will only collide with it not go through it. The armature has damped track if it matters. Suggestions about 3rd party plugins is welcome, though if you know a way without it I would like to know about it

Answer (score 0):

1. Select your object in Blender and go to the Physics Properties tab (the icon looks like a bouncing ball).
2. Click on the Add button and select Collision from the dropdown menu(adjust the collision according to your needs)
3. If you want your object to interact with other make sure that Collision physics types enabled.

You said that your object is attached to a rig, add a rigid body(type - passive) and adjust settings according to your needs

See if it helps...

Comment: It doesn't work, I've added collision to the green object, then a passive rigidbody on the pink object. Did I did it wrong?

Comment: (https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/physics/rigid_body/introduction.html#creating-a-rigid-body) You can refer blender docs you might find a solution there